# How to change the locale with momentjs?

Tags: momentjs

I know that there are quite a few similar questions around the web, but neither helped.

I guess this should log `hu`, but it logs `en` instead.

`import moment from 'moment'
import 'moment/locale/hu'
moment.locale('hu')
console.log(moment.locale())`

I'm running moment@2.23.0

Of course, not just the logging is unexpected, but no string is translated. I've tried changing the locale at the moment instance level too, but without success.

Following the above code both these should provide Hungarian string, but they log in English.

`console.log(moment().format('ddd, MMM Do, YYYY'))
console.log(moment().locale('hu').format('ddd, MMM Do, YYYY'))`

What do I miss?

Comment: What is the environment? Seems to work fine on node v10.14.2

Comment: @slessans, in the browser (it's a react app).